# AngularJS Injector Error Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I am new to AngularJS and I am trying to follow some structure for scalable applications, as well as trying to get Firebase working.  However, I am getting a simple error on the injector.  When I view the error tree, it seems to be all AngularJS references, and I do not see a reference to an object in my code.  I guess I am looking in the wrong place?

```
Failed to instantiate module MyApp due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.11/$injector/unpr?p0=e
    at Error (native)
    at     https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.min.js:6:417
    at      https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.min.js:38:307
    at d     (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.min.js:36:308)
    at Object.e [as invoke]     (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.min.js:37:64)
    at d     (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.min.js:35:301)
    at     https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.min.js:35:425
    at s     (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.min.js:7:302)
    at g     (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.min.js:35:202)
    at Ob     (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.min.js:38:435
```

[This is my Plunkr sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/P11jBXpvL3gRh2A7xBDK?p=linter)

Comment: it seems there is a typo in you sample, `templateUrl` not `templateURL`. Besides, I don't see any injector error, everything is fine.

Comment: I got this error when my `angular.module('appname', ['somemodule'])' ` was still calling `somemodule`. I had removed files relating to that module but had forgotten to remove that module name off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you don't get `$scope` right.

For `routeProvider`, it's `templateUrl` instead of `templateURL`. For `TeamCtrl`, if you want to bind a object to View, remember to add this object to `$scope`.

```
angular.module('MyApp').config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        controller: 'TeamCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'team.html'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });

});

angular.module('MyApp').controller('TeamCtrl', ['$scope', '$firebase', 'Teams', 
    function ($scope, $firebase, Teams) {

        $scope.Teams = Teams;
        $scope.team = {};

        $scope.SaveTeam = function(team) {
            $scope.Teams.$add({
                Id: $scope.team.id,
                Name: $scope.team.Name,
                Wins: $scope.team.Wins,
                Losses: $scope.team.Losses
            });
        };

        $scope.team.id = "";
        $scope.team.Name = "";
        $scope.team.Wins = "";
        $scope.team.Losses = "";
    }
]);
```

For `team.html`

```
<div ng-repeat="team in Teams">
    <h2>{{team.Name}}</h2>
    {{team.Wins}} / {{team.Losses}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I had placed everything together in one file for Plunkr, instead of the broken out ones I have, hence the 'angular.module('MyApp')' instead of using 'var app =' which may mean that my dependency is based on the inclusions. I will have to check the combine JavaScript.  I guess I need to check the code again on my side. Mostly trying to see how to work through the AngularJS error.